# Does Anyone know how to generate the pair address of a deployed token before LP is added?

Tags: uniswap, addresses

Does Anyone know how to generate the pair address of a deployed token before LP is added?

these are for tokens most likely going to be tradeable on uniswap v2 but willing to open my ears for any sort of help on this topic,

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014

```
keccak256( 0xff ++ address ++ salt ++ keccak256(init_code))[12:]
```

Where address is the factory contract, salt is the keccak on the packed encoding of (token0,token1), and init code is keccak of pool initialisation bytecode. Can grab latter from the factory contract under pairCodeHash.

```py
>>> address
'0xc35DADB65012eC5796536bD9864eD8773aBc74C4'
>>> token0
'0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6'
>>> token1
'0xC04B0d3107736C32e19F1c62b2aF67BE61d63a05'
>>> init
'0xe18a34eb0e04b04f7a0ac29a6e80748dca96319b42c54d679cb821dca90c6303'
>>> 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6 < 0xC04B0d3107736C32e19F1c62b2aF67BE61d63a05
True
>>>
>>> salt = w3.keccak(encode_packed(['address','address'],[token0,token1]))
>>> pre = '0xff'
>>> r = w3.keccak(HexBytes(pre) + HexBytes(address) + HexBytes(salt) + HexBytes(init))
>>> to_checksum_address(r[12:].hex())
'0xF5a767E375c5728e82Eb855A2007d218b860deaC
```

https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xF5a767E375c5728e82Eb855A2007d218b860deaC